# php - GET function to dynamic java script code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that generates dynamic code base on the user input.

Now I have a table that one of the columns is a multiple dropdown select box.

the values for the drop down come from a php address.

How can I get the dropdown to generate in a dynamic way with the rest of my table.

p.s. 
I know I'm suppose to get it with a get ajax function but I'm not sending any values just getting them from the database. So any example of it would be great.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function(e) {

    $("#Table").empty();
    //myCall();
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#NumOfLevels").val() >0) {
      var size = $("#NumOfLevels").val();
      var str='';
      var values = '<$php do {  $> <option value="<$php echo $row_rsCatalog["CatalogName"]$>"> <$php echo $row_rsCatalog["CatalogName"]$></option><$php } while ($row_rsCatalog = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCatalog));$rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCatalog);if($rows > 0) { mysql_data_seek($rsCatalog, 0);$row_rsCatalog = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCatalog);}$>';
      str+='<table align="center" width="694" border="0" cellspacing="3"  cellpadding="0">';
      str+='<tr><th style="width:auto" scope="col">Level </th><th width="107">Score</th><th width="58">File</th><th width="80">Link</th><th width="93">StartDate</th><th width="85">EndDate</th></tr>';


      for(var i = 0; i< size ; i++) {
        str+='<tr><td id="stage'+i+'" style="width:auto">no.  '+(i+1)+'</td><td><span id="sprytextfield4"><input type="text"  name="Score" id="Score"/>';
        str+='<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>';
        str+='<td><input type="file" name="gameFile" id="gameFile" /></td>';
        str+='<td><select multiple="multiple" name="CatlogLink" id="CatlogLink">';
        str+=values;
        str+='</select></td>';
        str+='<td><input type="text" class="date" id="datepicker" ></td>';
        str+='<td><input type="text" class="date" id="datepicker2" "></td>';
        //str.find('input').datepicker();
      }

      //str+='</tr></table>';

      $("#Table").append(str);
      var btn = '';
      btn+='<tr><td width="192" colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="שליחה"/></td>';
      btn+='<td width="309" colspan="4" align="center"><input type="reset" name="reset" id="Clear" value="ניקוי" /></td></tr></tr></table>';
      $("#Table tr:last").after(btn);


    }
    $(".date").click(function() {
      $( ".date" ).datepicker();
      $( ".date" ).datepicker();
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you're supposed to create php source with jquery? the one is interpreted on the web server, the other is being generated dynamically in the instance of the source the browser has loaded, however without a web server to interpret the server-side scripting this won't help you much... Besides showing how your page is supposed to work (thus exposing it for malicious access attempts), this would be a bunch of source the browser would simply show or skip but won't interpret as php...

Of course I might not understand what you're trying to achieve here and be mistaken, but this is how it looks to me..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). You should still use ajax get (or getJSON) to acquire the data from your database using php.

A very simple example:

**(script.js)**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json", // Used to decipher response from PHP
    url: "function.php", // The PHP file that will return your data
    // data: data, // This is not needed if your PHP script doesn't need it
    success: function (response) {
        // I would do console.log(response) to check what your PHP script returns
    }
});
```

**(function.php)**

```
// If you send data in the above ajax call, it can be retrieved through $_GET
// EG
// data: {test:"hello world"} would be retrieved
// at $_GET['test'] and contain the string "hello world"

// Query and retrieve data from your database
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1),
    array('id' => 2) // and so on...
);
// $response should be some kind of array (that way json_encode won't error out)
$response = array('data' => $data);

echo json_encode($response); // Will output a json encoded string so that the ajax call can decipher it
exit; // This would exit the script, so anything after this statement won't run.
// Note: If you echo anything after the json_encode then the ajax call won't be able to decipher the response.
```

In script.js' success function, the response would look something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point, you can loop through `response.data` (because it would be an array) to build your dropdown (or other HTML elements)

One thing I might add here, you should **refrain** from using PHP code in your javascript code as things could get very confusing. It's always better to keep things separated (javascript in js files and PHP in php files)